# How to get keydown and keyup events on Kindle Fire HD with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can only get the keydown event to fire on a new Kindle Fire HD tablet for the delete and enter keys.

I am using the built-in Silk browser.  I can see that on Google, the keydown event is being fired.  How did they get it to work?

If I go to a keyboard testing website like http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html in the Silk browser, then it does not fire either.  Anybody have a workaround for this?

```
$("#simpleSearch_input").keydown(function(evt) {
    alert("keydown");
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your keydown code inside `$(document).on( 'pageinit',function(event){....` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {...` or `$(function() {...`?

Comment: The code is in the pageinit.  I can't use the document.ready because I am using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Maybe the keydown does not work because the Kindle fire is not fully supported by jQuery Mobile???

Comment: Not sure. Does something like the [JQuery Autocomplete demo](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/autocomplete/) work on the Kindle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the 'input' event instead of 'keyup'

The order of keyboard events(HTML5) is keydown->keypress->input->keyup.

The input event will be missing some properties that the keyup also passes such as keyCode / metaKey/shiftKey/altKey

I used:

var inputEV = 'oninput' in window ? 'input' : 'keyup'

to define the event that triggered my autocomplete call in the Silk browser.

jQuery code used on jsfiddle to test it.

```
(function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var inputEV = 'oninput' in window ? 'input' : 'keyup';
                $('#listen').on(inputEV,function(event){                        
                    $('#show').val($('#show').val()+'\n'+event.type);
                    console.log('--- input event ----');
                    for(var v in event.originalEvent){ 
                        if(event.hasOwnProperty(v)){
                            console.log(v+' |--> '+event[v]);
                        }
                    }
                })
                //just added to see what Silk listens for on the keyup event
                $('#listen').on('keyup',function(event){                        
                    $('#show').val($('#show').val()+'\n'+event.type+' | which --> '+event.which);
                    console.log('--- keyup event ----');
                    for(var v in event.originalEvent){ 
                        if(event.hasOwnProperty(v)){
                            console.log(v+' |--> '+event[v]);
                        }
                    }
                })                  
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

link on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/visionmonster/eJJna/embedded/result/

As in the original question I could only get the Silk browser to listen to the keyup for delete / enter

HTML5 spec:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#handler-oninput